# Your app is using a version of MoPub containing a security vulnerability

Tags: mopub

Your app is using a version of MoPub containing a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

[image: Desc]

Answer (score 0):

Resubmit your application with MoPub SDK v4.4.0 or higher.

See https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6345928?hl=en for more details.

Download the latest version of MoPub here: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk

Comment: please provide steps to be taken.then links.

Comment: To upgrade to MoPub v4.4.0 or higher, follow the integration instructions [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started). The instructions for SDK v4.3.0 or lower (where the security vulnerability exists) and the instructions for v4.4.0 and higher are very similar.